# Обновить данные в .subscribe()

Tags: angular2, firebase, angular, firebase-database

Всем привет! Я использую Angular и Firebase для работы с данными. В базе хранятся  статьи. Мне нужно обновлять счетчик просмотров у статьи, каждый раз, когда открывается страница с этой статьей.

Вот так я получаю статью с базы:

**article.service.ts**

```
getById(id: string): Observable<Article> {
  return this.db
    .collection('articles').doc(id)
    .snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(map(doc => {
      return {
        id: doc.payload.id,
        ...doc.payload.data()
      } as Article;
    }));
}
```

Вот так получаю в компоненте:

**article.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
  let articleId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
  this.getArticle(articleId);
}

getArticle(id: string) {
  this.articleService.getById(id).subscribe(article => {
    this.article = article;

    // тут пытаюсь обновить счетчик
    this.article.views++;
    this.articleService.update(this.article);
  });
}
```

Однако при обновлении в `.subscribe()` счетчик зацикливается и происходит бесконечное обновление. Если обновлять за пределами `.subscribe()`, то будет ошибка, что `this.article = undefined`.

Как правильно обновлять счетчик?

Comment: А почему обновление то приводит к зацикливанию? Приложите весь код или хотя бы пример ге либо.

Comment: Вы вызываете getById из update сервиса?

Comment: во-первых ты показал только место где "якобы" происходит зацикливание. во-вторых `snapshotChanges` возвращает горячий поток, который генерирует события от сокета. Если тебе нужно получить документ 1 раз то для этого используется `take(1)` или `first`